# PHP - How to get $_GET Parameter without value

Tags: php, parse-url

I need to know how to get the $_GET parameter from requested url. If I use for example

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parse_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

`echo $parse_url;` will output query=1, but I need only the parameter not parameter AND value to check if parameter is in array.

Comment: All the URL are equals: `term=value` or they can be different? You need always the last value after `=`?

Comment: Use `@array_keys($_GET)[0]` to get the parameter name of the first parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, simply exploding the `=` might quickly suits your need.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parse_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$queryparam = explode("=", $parse_url);
echo $queryparam[0];
/* OUTPUT query */

if (in_array($queryparam[0], $array_of_params)){ ... }
```

But you can simply achieve the same thing like this:

```
if (@$_GET["query"] != ""){ ... }
```

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcards for explode? I have queries like filter[2]=, so "=" doesn't work and must use "%" instead.

Comment: @NVRAM why use ``$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`` and then use ``parse_url``, better use ``$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`` to just return the query params ??

Comment: Can you paste the complete url params, example `?query=3&filter=some%20stuffs` You can explode by `&` then explode again for example. Some others answers can help also for this.
@OMi Shah  Yes absolutely! There is many ways,others answers are correct too.

Comment: Solution from @NVRAM is okay. I need only the first parameter. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] will output all queries.

Comment: This one of multiple examples: filter[2]=&filter[3]=27. I need only the first parameter. Buth there are also queries available with simple query like query=1 without [] in parameter. But need solution for both.

Comment: hmm okay then :)

Comment: `echo preg_replace("/\[.\]/", "",'filter[6]');` output `filter`. But won't throw an error if there is no brackets^

Comment: I already tried it with preg_replace, but my knowledge about using patterns wasn' t good enough, so it will take a little bit time to check your solution.

Comment: No worries, learning them now! You can achieve the same with just explode in chain (and other ways too!). Good luck!

Comment: I've just checked your last solution with preg_replace, but doesn't work. If I use

`$lc_request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parsed_url = parse_url($lc_request_uri, PHP_URL_QUERY);
echo preg_replace("/\[.\]/", "",$parsed_url);`

Output for echo: filter%5B2%5D=22 
for Query: filter[2]=22

Comment: `echo preg_replace("/\[.*/",  "",  urldecode("filter[2]=22"));` output `filter`

Comment: I already fixed it 
`$lc_request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parsed_url = parse_url($lc_request_uri, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$url_replace = preg_replace("/\%5B.\%5D/", "", $parsed_url);
if (isset($url_replace)) {
$cleanquery = explode("=", $url_replace);
} else {
 $cleanquery = explode("=", $parsed_url);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
// Example URL: http://somewhere.org?id=42&name=bob

// An array to store the parameters
$params = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params);

// Access what you need like this:
echo 'ID: ' .$params['id'];
```

Comment: Again and forget what I need the $_GET parameter for. I want to parse a URL to get only the parameter name and not the parameter && value. If query_string is query=1 I need "query".

Answer (score 0):

The Arry $_GET contains all needed informations. $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] and parse_url not needed.
As an example I have the following browser line:

```
http://localhost/php/test.php?par&query=1
```

Let's see what $ _GET contains

```
echo '<pre>';
var_export($_GET);
```

Output

```
array (
  'par' => '',
  'query' => '1',
)
```

With array_keys() I get all keys.

```
$keys = array_keys($_GET);
var_export($keys);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'par',
  1 => 'query',
)
```

The first key I get with (see also comment from @bobble bubble)

```
echo $keys[0];  //par
```

or

```
echo key($_GET);
```

With array_key_exists () I can check whether a key is available.

```
if(array_key_exists('query',$_GET)){
  echo 'query exists';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) too, it *Returns trailing name component of path*. For example:

```
$lastPart=explode("=",basename('http://yourdomain.com/path/query=1'));
echo $lastPart[0];
```

**Output**

```
query
```

Comment: See my last reply regarding wildcards for explode